# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of null - is my solution valid/correct

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage

I'm trying to push an object into an array named "contactBook" which is then stored into the local storage and i get the following error -

This is the error description for all solutions(from research) that didn't work -

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of null

I have tried several solutions which aren't working. I have figured out a solution but not sure if it's a valid solution!

I have done a lot of research on this via Stack Overflow, MDN, Google, Youtube and other sites to find a solution but nothing worked until I tried something different, something that surprisingly wasn't in the research.

I'm asking this because the working solution I have used has not been presented in ANY of the research I have done. It was just something where I thought "heck, let me just try it and see if it works". I figured that the item key/value "addbook" and "[]" needs to be set first.

So I'm thinking, is this solution actually valid?

```
let contactBook = (localStorage.getItem('addbook')) ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('addbook')) : localStorage.setItem('addbook', JSON.stringify([]));;
```

Original code before solution that didn't work -

```
let contactBook = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('addbook')) || [];
```

Solution 1 that didn't work -

```
let contactBook = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('addbook'));

  if (contactBook === null) {
    contactBook = [];
  };
```

Solution 2 that didn't work -

```
let contactBook = (localStorage.getItem('todoList')) ?JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('addbook')) : [];
```

All of these researched solutions work on the local host but not on a live server except for my solution the one that works.

Is my solution valid even though it works and why does all solutions work on local host and not on a live server?

Here is the full site/app where you'll be able to navigate to the full js.app via developer tools http://www.darsh-p.tk/diary/index.html

Comment: The error is quite clear: you are trying to push an array element into an object that has not been allocated as yet. You can test that by `if (typeof <your element> == "undefined")`. If the condition is true, it means that you have nothing allocated for your element. Try initializing it with `var <your element> = []`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...

Am I not initialising it with  <br/>
let contactBook = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('addbook')) || [];  <br/>
??

Comment: Try `contactBook = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('addbook') + "[]");`

Comment: FDavidov - thank you for your help but that didn't work. The browser throws a syntax error for "[]" so I removed the quotes and I get the same  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of null" error.

Comment: so is my solution not valid? let contactBook = (localStorage.getItem('addbook')) ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('addbook')) : localStorage.setItem('addbook', JSON.stringify([]));;

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't explain what you are trying to achieve. I guess you're trying to push data into the array. In that case,

```
let contactBook = [];
const contactBookStr = localStorage.getItem('addbook');

if (contactBookStr) {
  try {
    let contactBook = JSON.parse(contactBookStr);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('The data stored in "addbook" is invalid.');
  }
}

//...your code continues..
```

This should work. `JSON.parse()` would throw an error if the value is an invalid JSON object so you need to catch the error and handle it.

You should note that depending on how your application is meant to work, your solution is not likely to give you your desired result because `localStorage.setItem()` returns `undefined`.

Comment: thanks for the reply... never used try or catch before, will need to look into that.

Comment: @Darsh2987 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

Answer (score 0):

Let's examine your code:

```
let contactBook = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('addbook')) || [];
```

This means that you have the variable `contactBook` and you are assigning to it an object (JSON) to which you are ORing `[]`.

If the result of `localStorage.getItem('addbook')` is a string, you can do:

```
let contactBook[localStorage.getItem('addbook')] = [] ;
```

For instance, if `localStorage.getItem('addbook')` returns "abcd", then you will have `contactBook.abcd[]` being an array object.

If you want to push elements into `contactBook`, simple:

```
let contactBook = [] ;
contactBook.push(<object>) ;
```